# How to pass an argument when invoking a method (reflection)?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to call a method, passing an int. using the following code I can fetch the method but not passing the argument. How to fix it?

```
dynamic obj;
obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}", namespaceName, className)));

var method = this.obj.GetType().GetMethod(this.methodName, new Type[] { typeof(int) });
bool isValidated = method.Invoke(this.obj, new object[1]);

public void myMethod(int id)
{
}
```

Comment: `method.Invoke(this.obj, new Object[]{ 1 /* id */ });`

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779731/how-to-pass-a-parameter-as-a-reference-with-methodinfo-invoke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new object[1]` part is how you're specifying the arguments - but you're just passing in an array with a single `null` reference. You want:

```
int id = ...; // Whatever you want the value to be
object[] args = new object[] { id };
method.Invoke(obj, args);
```

(See the [`MethodBase.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for more details.)

Note that `method.Invoke` returns `object`, not `bool`, so your current code wouldn't even compile. You could cast the return value to `bool`, but in your example that wouldn't help at execution time as `myMethod` returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an object with the invoke method

```
namespace test
{
   public class A
   {
       public int n { get; set; }
       public void NumbMethod(int Number)
       {
            int n = Number;
            console.writeline(n);
       }
    }
}
class MyClass
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        test mytest = new test();   
        Type myTypeObj = mytest.GetType();    
        MethodInfo myMethodInfo = myTypeObj.GetMethod("NumbMethod");
        object[] parmint = new object[] {5};
        myMethodInfo.Invoke(myClassObj, parmint);
    }
 }
```