# Returning a list as output parameter using methodInfo.Invoke

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to return a collection as out parameter from a dynamically invoked method using reflection . The issue I am facing is that I  am unable to get the updated collection from the method .  Please find the code snippet below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Run();
}

public void Run()
{
    //Dictionary - this is for further 
    Dictionary<string, object> xmlArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Employee def = new Employee(10, 10000);
    xmlArgs["SalaryLimit"] = 2000;
    xmlArgs["Employee"] = new List<Employee> { def };
    //Create Instance of the method 
    MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetEmployee");
    // Adding parameters 
    List<object> args = new List<object>();
    foreach (ParameterInfo pi in mi.GetParameters())
    {
        args.Add(xmlArgs[pi.Name]);
    }
    //Invoke
    mi.Invoke(this, args.ToArray());
    //The collect is not updated below . ????
    List<Employee> filter = (List<Employee>)args[1];
}

public List<Employee> GetEmployee(int SalaryLimit, out List<Employee> Employee)
{
    List<Employee> objEmpList = new List<Employee>();
    objEmpList.Add(new Employee(1, 1000));
    objEmpList.Add(new Employee(2, 2000));
    objEmpList.Add(new Employee(3, 3000));
    objEmpList.Add(new Employee(4, 4000));
    objEmpList.Add(new Employee(5, 5000));
    Employee = objEmpList.Where(x => x.Salary > SalaryLimit).ToList();
    return objEmpList;
}
}

public class Employee
{
    public Employee() { }
    public Employee(int Id, int Salary)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Salary = Salary;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using reflection when you know the type and method name?

Comment: Could it be that, on the line where you call `mi.Invoke(this, args.ToArray());'  the `IEnumerable.ToArray()` method returns a new array object, whose reference gets passed to the Invoke method, **not** the original `args` collection, and it is the reference to the array that gets updated as an output rather than the original list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a parameter as a reference with MethodInfo.Invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779731/how-to-pass-a-parameter-as-a-reference-with-methodinfo-invoke)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
    mi.Invoke(this, args.ToArray());
    //The collect is not updated below . ????
    List<Employee> filter = (List<Employee>)args[1];
```

When you use `Invoke` to call a method with an `out` parameter - the appropriate position *in the parameter array* is updated with the new value.  Since you call `ToArray()` inline, you don't have a reference to the actual array that was passed to `Invoke`, only the list that was used to *create* the array.  Try changing your code to:

```
    object[] args2 = args.ToArray();
    mi.Invoke(this, args2);
    List<Employee> filter = (List<Employee>)args2[1];  // pull the output form the _array_, not the _list_.
```

Note that you also don't need to have an object in the output position (it doesn't hurt anything, but it will be overwritten in the array).