# Invoking dynamic method with parameters based on a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to call a method based on a string. It works fine using [MethodInfo.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx).

What I would like to know if there is a way to add parameters to the call, based on the same string, e.g. instead of calling `foo()` I would like to call `foo(1, true, "bar")`.

I suppose I'd have to extract the parameters, convert them to their correct primitive type and invoke the method using `methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, params)`.

It feels like a long shot, but is there an "OK" way of solving this?

Comment: maybe it's will answer you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779731/how-to-pass-a-parameter-as-a-reference-with-methodinfo-invoke

Comment: Can you give more info on the application of this?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's a webforms app where I would like a user to be able to select a dynamic data source. To be more specific, it's a data source for a crystal report web report parameter.

Comment: How do the functions differ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman They don't exist yet, but basically I would like the user to have the possibility to override a methods default behavior by passing some optional arguments.

Comment: Can't you rely on an interface implementation or something like that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure, but regardless of the method signatures, how should the arguments be passed?

Comment: Maybe as a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

What level of variance are we talking about? Do all parameters need to be completely dynamic, i.e., different types, different number, different order. Or are there a set of optional parameters of known order and type?

If dynamic, then an object dictionary/array is possibly the only solution. Otherwise, known parameters can be declared with default values, making them optional:

```
public void SomeMethod(int one = 0, string two = "default", bool three = true)
```

Comment: The type will be known, though the number may differ, which can be solved with overloads or default values as you're saying. My biggest problem would still be converting values from strings to their correct type.

Comment: It depends on the usage. Surely parameters passed in will be expected by the code to which they are passed? Each parameter in an object array can be converted to the appropriate type then? How are you using the parameters?

Comment: To elaborate, the string could look like this: `foo("bar", true)`, which would require me to extract `"bar"` and `true`, add them to an `object[]`, and pass it as the second argument to the `Invoke()` method. I was hoping for an alternative solution, but I can't think of any since I'm stuck with the string

Comment: I was thinking that it would rather be `foo(object[] values)` and the `foo()` method would pass the array on. So the calling code would simply compose the object array and pass it in. The receiving code (called by foo) could would know how to extract the values it needs. This is a standard mechanism I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking as well. But still, the 2 values will have to be extracted and converted to a `new object[] { "bar", true }`. Guess I'll have to split the string or something like that...