# How to pass a ref parameter from managed c++ to c# method using reflection

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm having trouble passing ref parameter from managed C++ wrapper to C# method from dynamically loaded library.
Returning value of parameter is 0.

C# method

```
void method(ref int param)
```

C++/CLI wrapper invoking method with tracking reference

```
Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(assemblyName);
Type^ type = assembly->GetType(typeName);
gcroot<Object^> instance = Activator::CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo^ method = instance->GetType()->GetMethod(methodName);

System::Int32^% refParam = gcnew System::Int32;
method->Invoke(instance, gcnew array<Object^> { refParam });
//refParam value is 0
```

Comment: You should read updated value back from array passed to `Invoke` method.

Comment: I think I should be able to read refParam. Isn't tracking reference equivalent to C# ref?

Comment: No, it changes the way the method is called, not the type of the argument.  Also get rid of gcroot.

Comment: I'd suggest translating the c# code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779751) to [How to pass a parameter as a reference with MethodInfo.Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8779731) into c++/cli.  The relevant sentence seems to be *If it were a `ref` parameter (instead of `out`) then the initial value would be used - but the value in the array could still be **replaced** by the method.*

Comment: Reading value from array solved my issue.

Comment: @earthless - Then you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to read updated value from array passed to `Invoke` method.

```
array<Object^>^ args = gcnew array<Object^> { refParam };
method->Invoke(instance, args);

int value = (int)args[0];
```