# dynamic DLL call with ref-param causes CS1502 + basic DLL understanding issues

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am using Visual Studio and C# (exact version can be chosen if necessary). I try to dynamically call a function from a .NET driver.DLL and get an error "The best overloaded method match for 'name' has some invalid arguments" (at least that seems to be the translation of the error, so it should be CS1502 according to my own search... where can I even see the error ID?)

With direct DLL reference I can simply run:

```
using driverDllNamespace;
driverClass classInstance = new driverClass();
driverCfgType driverCfg = new driverCfgType();
classInstance.getConfig(ref driverCfg);
```

But with reflection/dynamics I try a similar thing:

```
Assembly driverDLL = Assembly.LoadFile("C:\vendorname\driver.dll");
typesDict = driverDll.GetExportedTypes(); // simplified
dynamic classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typesDict["driverClass"]; // works
dynamic driverCfg = Activator.CreateInstance(types["driverCfgType"]); // works
classInstance.getConfig(ref driverCfg); // crashes 'best overloaded method... has some invalid arguments
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I call a function with ref-parameter dynamically?

Thanks for your help! :)

While this is a specific problem I need help with, I also generally struggle to understand how DLLs should be used correctly.
I want to create an application for different target PCs (same OS) that might have different driver versions installed. These drivers are what I am trying to call. The installation path of the drivers might also differ from PC to PC.
So far, when using DLLs, I simply added a reference in my Visual Studio project and used the DLL like any other .NET class. In my understanding it uses that referenced DLL as a fixed path and somehow copies it to the bin-folder of my application - right?
How does that even work if said DLL has dependencies like e.g. installation path?
For my current use case in my current understanding I have to dynamically call the DLL on the target PC with the right path, correct? Thus referencing a DLL during compilation time won't do the trick, right?
(Sorry for asking stupid questions - I am really trying to understand this.)

Comment: Don't call it dll. Its an assembly. If you call it dll everyone will think of something unmanaged. What does different versions mean here or rather how different can they be? Do they at least share the same interface?

Comment: What's the difference here? The DLL I am using is a .NET-DLL, would it be different for other DLLs? 
And yes, DLL is expected to always have the same interface. If it does not, my application will handle the error. 
But in my tests I use the same DLL via reference and dynamically, but dynamic does not work for the function call with ref-parameter. So I am stuck with an issue that is not caused by the DLL itself but by my handling of it. All other calls seem to work fine so far, but this is blocking me.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading)

Comment: I beleive Ralfs point is that if you talk about "dll" in the context of c#, people might assume you are talking about native interop. Sure ".net dll" makes if fairly clear, but "Assembly" is most likely a better term to use. If dynamic does not work you might need to use reflection & methodInfo, See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779731/how-to-pass-a-parameter-as-a-reference-with-methodinfo-invoke)

Comment: With shared interface i meant an actual net interfaces not the idea of of the same set of methods. A typical pattern is an own interface assembly that can be normally referenced at compile time. And then at runtime load the implementation like you do and cast the thing you create via the Activator to that interface.  I assume you don't have such an assembly alongside the driver assembly?